# Using VBA to loop through table rows with WorksheetFunction.Index

Tags: excel, vba

I want to loop through the rows in a specific table column and can't figure out the correct syntax. How do I fix this?

```
count = Application.count(Range("tbl_summ[ColA]"))  ' number of rows
For k = 1 To count
        Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(tbl_summ[ColA], k).Select
...
```

I also tried the below but it didn't work either.

```
        Application.WorksheetFunction.Index("tbl_summ[ColA]", k).Select
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try next one:

```
Count = Application.Count(Range("tbl_summ[ColA]"))  ' number of rows
For k = 1 To Count
    Range("tbl_summ[ColA]").Cells(k).Select
Next
```

or you can use `For Each` as well:

```
Dim tblCell As Range

For Each tblCell In Range("tbl_summ[ColA]")
    tblCell.Select
Next
```